# Some values in crystal report parameters doesn't appear

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I get some data by crystal report, and I use the parameters to let the users choosing their filters, but the problem is the crystal report (in parameters window) doesn't give all data from the column.

example:
I have a column that contains: (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) but the crystal report parameter window gives me just (x1,x3,x4) although when I retrieve the data into Datagridview I get the correct data that contains all options (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5).

note: I use a dynamic parameter.

Comment: I've had similar issues with dynamic parameter fields, but usually its because I'm dealing with hundreds of values.  Is your problem occurring with only a small number of values loaded into your dynamic parameter, or is your question down-playing the number of values for the sake of making your example easier to explain?

Comment: I ask the question in my previous comment because I wanted to point out that Crystal Report has a limitation that prevents loading more than 1000 values into a dynamic parameter.  And when have less than 1000, it will use an unusual control object to split the data between several pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://answers.sap.com/questions/105171/increasing-maxrowsetrecords.html
Here's the text:

Resolution

CAUTION The following resolution involves editing the registry. Using the Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall the Microsoft Windows operating system. Use the Registry Editor at your own risk. For information on how to edit the registry key, view the 'Changing Keys and Values' online Help topic in the Registry Editor (Regedit.exe). It is strongly recommended that you make a backup copy of the registry files before you edit the registry.
To increase the maximum number of values for a dynamic parameter list of values, set the registry key: MaxRowsetRecords, to a value greater than 1,000:
Open the Microsoft Registry Editor, and navigate to the path corresponding to the version of Crystal Reports used:
Crystal Reports 2008:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
  Crystal Reports 2011:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
  Crystal Reports 2013:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
  Crystal Reports 2016:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
  Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV
  NOTES:
- Add the key: LOV, if it is not present.
- For 64 bit version of Microsoft Windows, the registry path will be slightly different, it will start with:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node...

But the rest of the registry path is the same.
Add the String value: MaxRowsetRecords
Set the value of: MaxRowsetRecords to the maximum number of records in the table where the values are stored. If Crystal Reports application needs to scan 100 000 records to retrieve 20 000 parameter values, set the value to 100 000.

IMPRTANT NOTES:

- The higher the number of values set, the longer it will take to see the dynamic parameter prompt screen. In brief, it impacts the performance.
- The value 0 (Unlimited) will not work with BusinessObjects Enterprise XI or Crystal Reports Server XI, you must specify another value.
  Close Crystal Reports Designer and then make the changes to the registry, reopen Crystal Reports, or restart the Crystal Reports services for the BusinessObjects platforms.